PoolEnrich loading the entire file content in memory in camel 4.4.0 version
We had an app which consumes sqs message and download S3 file based on the SQS message and it is working good in camel 3.2.0 version.
Now we upgraded our camel version from 3.2.0 to 4.4.0 and found pollEnrich is loading entire file in memory in camel 4.4.0 due to following code in AWS2S3Consumer.java(camel 4.4.0) s3Object is ResponseInputStream in new version
 public Exchange createExchange(ExchangePattern pattern, ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> s3Object, String key) {
        LOG.trace("Getting object with key [{}] from bucket [{}]...", key, getConfiguration().getBucketName());

        LOG.trace("Got object [{}]", s3Object);

        Exchange exchange = createExchange(true);
        exchange.setPattern(pattern);
        Message message = exchange.getIn();

        if (!getConfiguration().isIgnoreBody()) {
            if (getConfiguration().isIncludeBody()) {
                try {
                    message.setBody(IoUtils.toByteArray(s3Object));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeCamelException(e);
                }
            } else {
                message.setBody(s3Object);
            }
        }

In Camel 3.2.0 PoolErich only get file handle instead of entire file content
Code in S3Consumer.java (camel 3.2.0)
protected Queue<Exchange> createExchanges(List<S3ObjectSummary> s3ObjectSummaries) {
        if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
            LOG.trace("Received {} messages in this poll", s3ObjectSummaries.size());
        }

        Collection<S3Object> s3Objects = new ArrayList<>();
        Queue<Exchange> answer = new LinkedList<>();
        try {
            for (S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary : s3ObjectSummaries) {
                S3Object s3Object = getAmazonS3Client().getObject(s3ObjectSummary.getBucketName(), s3ObjectSummary.getKey());
                s3Objects.add(s3Object);

                Exchange exchange = getEndpoint().createExchange(s3Object);
                answer.add(exchange);
            }

tried with "includeBody=false" option while pollEnriching . But still it is loading entire file.
Can any one help me to resolve this issue
Thanks
